# When deployed, asp.net page will not run onload or postback event functions from server side

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

in my asp.net application (VB is server side background) - I have a page that will not run onload or postback server side events. In the local development build, it runs correctly but when published on an amazon EC2 instance the onload doesn't seem to execute, and even though the post back is happening (tested with onload javascript alerts to make sure the post back was happening) - when the dropdown named drpdn_status is changed, the server side function to handle this does not seem to be executing. Can anyone see why this would be happening? Listed below is the page code, followed by the server side on load and the selectedIndexChanged function to handle the change of the dropdown

Page Code

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="toDoListModifyEntity_PT.aspx.vb" inherits="iPlan.toDoListModifyEntity_PT" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Component" Namespace="components" Assembly="components" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControl" TagName="ConditionalDetails" Src="../include/ConditionalDetailsPanel.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControl" TagName="Deliverable" Src="../include/AttachmentToEntity.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControl" TagName="EntityPredecessorsTable" Src="../include/EntityPredListPanel.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<HEAD>
        <title><%=Application("BrowserTitle")%></title>
    <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
    <meta content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
    <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
    <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
    <LINK href="../solutions/DetailScreenTest.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <LINK href="../StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- includes for: calendar popUp -->
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../include/calendar.vRef.NET.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../include/ShowHelp.js"></script>
    <LINK href="../include/calendar.blueIce.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles.css">
</HEAD>
<body>
    <form id="Form2" method="post" runat="server">
        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="pageHeader">Update this Task</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="hideforprint" style="HEIGHT: 30px">
            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" onclick="showHelp('../', 'pendingtasks.htm')" alt="Help on Detail Screen"
                            src="../images/helpdashboard.gif"></td>
                    <!--
                <td align="right" width="1%"><img onclick="window.parent.execScript('ToggleDetailDivSize()'); if (this.action == 'max') {this.action='restore'; this.src = '../images/bigRestore.gif'; this.alt='Restore Detail Screen';} else {this.action='max'; this.src = '../images/bigMax.gif'; this.alt='Maximize Detail Screen';}" 
                        action="max" 
                        alt="Maximize Detail Screen"
                        src="../images/bigMax.gif"
                        style="cursor: hand" ></td>
                -->
                    <td align="right" width="1%"><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" onclick="window.parent.execScript('ToggleDetailDiv()')" alt="Close Detail Screen"
                            src="../images/BigX.gif"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- START nav buttons-->
        <div class="hideforprint">
            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="pageHeader">
                        <table id="navControl_tlbNav" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <!--
                        <td class="infotext2" valign="Top" style="width:50px;"><img onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/task.gif')" onmouseout="imgOu(this, '../images/task_over.gif')" onclick="imgclick('../tasks/modifytask.aspx', '&amp;mode=create', 13)" src="../images/task_over.gif" border="0" style="cursor:hand;" /><br> Create Task</td>
                        <td class="infotext2" valign="Top" style="width:50px;"><img onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/Milestone.gif')" onmouseout="imgOu(this, '../images/Milestone.gif')" onclick="imgclick('../tasks/MilestoneLinking.aspx', '&amp;mode=create&amp;milestone=true', 13)" src="../images/Milestone.gif" border="0" style="cursor:hand;" /><br>Create Milestone</td>
                        <td class="infotext2" valign="Top" style="width:50px;"><img onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/modify.gif')" onmouseout="imgOu(this, '../images/modify_over.gif')" onclick="imgclick('../tasks/modifytask.aspx', '&amp;mode=edit', 13)" src="../images/modify_over.gif" border="0" style="cursor:hand;" /><br>Modify Task</td>
                        <td class="infotext2" valign="Top" style="width:50px;"><img onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/delete.gif')" onmouseout="imgOu(this, '../images/delete_over.gif')" onclick="imgclick('../tasks/deletetask.aspx', '', 13)" src="../images/delete_over.gif" border="0" style="cursor:hand;" /><br>Delete Task</td>
                        -->
                                <td class="infotext2" style="WIDTH: 50px" vAlign="top"><IMG onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/attachfile.gif')" style="CURSOR: hand" onclick="imgclick('../listing/attachments.aspx', '', 13)"
                                        onmouseout="imgOu(this, '../images/attachfile_over.gif')" src="../images/attachfile_over.gif" border="0"><br>
                                    Attach Files</td>
                                <td class="infotext2" style="WIDTH: 50px" vAlign="top"><IMG onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/DetailsScreenNotes_over.gif')" style="CURSOR: hand"
                                        onclick="imgclick('../notesforum/EntityNotes.aspx', '', 13)" onmouseout="imgOu(this, '../images/DetailsScreenNotes.gif')" src="../images/DetailsScreenNotes.gif"
                                        border="0"><br>
                                    Notes</td>
                                <td class="infotext2" style="WIDTH: 50px" vAlign="top"><IMG onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/PrintDetailsPage_over.gif')" style="CURSOR: hand"
                                        onclick="imgclick('print', '', 13)" onmouseout="imgOu(this, '../images/PrintDetailsPage.gif')" src="../images/PrintDetailsPage.gif"
                                        border="0"><br>
                                    Print Details</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- END nav buttons-->
        <!-- START NOTICES task predecessor list -->
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_msg_predecessorsInSameAction" Runat="server" Visible="False">
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                    <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                    <TD height="1" width="200">Notice</TD>
                    <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <TABLE class="detailTable" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%">
                <TR class="detailRow">
                    <TD class="detailLabel"><IMG src="../images/yellow-exclamation-sign.gif"></TD>
                    <TD class="detailLabel">This task is <SPAN class="DetailsOtherGreyed">grayed-out</SPAN>
                        pending the completion of the following predecessor Tasks. If this Task is 
                        updated, future status updates will be restricted until the Project Manager 
                        takes action.</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_msg_predecessorsActionLinked" Runat="server" Visible="False">
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                    <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                    <TD height="1" width="200">Notice</TD>
                    <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <TABLE class="detailTable" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%">
                <TR class="detailRow">
                    <TD class="detailLabel"><IMG src="../images/yellow-exclamation-sign.gif"></TD>
                    <TD class="detailLabel">This task is <SPAN class="DetailsOtherGreyed">grayed-out</SPAN>
                        pending the completion of the following predecessor Actions. If this Task is 
                        updated, future status updates will be restricted until the Administrator takes 
                        action.</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </asp:Panel>
        <!-- END NOTICES task predecessor list -->
        <!-- START NOTICES Status Marked Early -->
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_msg_earlyProgressAlreadyMarked_notifiedPM" Runat="server" Visible="False">
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                    <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                    <TD height="1" width="200">Notice</TD>
                    <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <TABLE class="detailTable" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%">
                <TR class="detailRow">
                    <TD class="detailLabel"><IMG src="../images/yellow-exclamation-sign.gif"></TD>
                    <TD class="detailLabel">Status for this Task has been marked and the Project 
                        Manager notified. Future status updates await Project Manager action. Please 
                        contact the PM for further information.</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl_msg_earlyProgressAlreadyMarked_notifiedAdmin" Runat="server" Visible="False">
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                    <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                    <TD height="1" width="200">Notice</TD>
                    <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <TABLE class="detailTable" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%">
                <TR class="detailRow">
                    <TD class="detailLabel"><IMG src="../images/yellow-exclamation-sign.gif"></TD>
                    <TD class="detailLabel">Status for this Task has been marked and an Administrator 
                        notified. Future status updates await Administrator action. Please contact the 
                        Administrator for further information.</TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </asp:Panel>
        <!-- END NOTICES Status Marked Early -->
        <!-- START task predecessor list -->
        <asp:panel id="pnl_predecessorList" Runat="server" visible="false">
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                    <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                    <TD height="1" width="200">Predecessors</TD>
                    <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE> <!-- <TABLE class="detailTable" id="Table3" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%"> -->
            <UserControl:EntityPredecessorsTable style="BORDER-BOTTOM: red thin solid; BORDER-LEFT: red thin solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: red; BORDER-TOP: red thin solid; BORDER-RIGHT: red thin solid; cGKattrib: hello chris"
                id="usrCntrl_EntityPredecessor" class="detailTable" runat="server" relativePathToImages="../images/" relativePathToRoot="../"
                width="100%" displayMode="PredecessorMode"></UserControl:EntityPredecessorsTable>
        </asp:panel>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_cGKDebug" Runat="server" Visible="False" />
        <script language="VB" runat="server">
    Private Sub usrCntrl_EntityPredecessor_EntityHasActionLink() Handles usrCntrl_EntityPredecessor.EntityHasPredecessorsActionLinked

        '"../ViewTask.aspx" & Request.QueryString.ToString
        lbl_cGKDebug.text += "TESTING JIZZ: ../tasks/ViewTask.aspx?" & Request.QueryString.ToString &" <br />"
        'Response.redirect("../tasks/ViewTask.aspx?" & Request.QueryString.ToString )


        pnl_predecessorList.Visible = True

        'Show user messages (only if global flags for both other early-status-marked notices are not on):
        if gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyAdmin = false and gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyPM = false then
            pnl_msg_predecessorsInSameAction.Visible = False
            pnl_msg_predecessorsActionLinked.Visible = True
        end if

        'Hide Modify Panel, Addt'nl Details
        pnl_dynDetails.visible = false
        pnl_modifyElements.visible = false

        btn_save.Text = "Inform Administrator"
        btn_save.visible = false
        lbl_btn_save_message.visible = true
        lbl_btn_save_message.Text = "You may not save status on this task."

        'Change the way the save function behaves:
        gbl_bool_predecessorsInOtherActionExist_notifyAdmin = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub usrCntrl_EntityPredecessor_EntityHasPredecessorsInSameAction() Handles usrCntrl_EntityPredecessor.EntityHasPredecessorsInSameAction
        lbl_debugInfo.Text += "<br />usrCntrl_EntityPredecessor_EntityHasNoPredecessors Sub: there's been an EVENT THIS IS GREAT<br />"

        pnl_predecessorList.Visible = True 'False

        'Show user messages (only if global flags for both other early-status-marked notices are not on):
        if gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyAdmin = false and gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyPM = false then
            pnl_msg_predecessorsInSameAction.Visible = True
            pnl_msg_predecessorsActionLinked.Visible = False
        end if

        btn_save.Text = "Inform PM" '"Save"

        'Change the way the save function behaves:
        gbl_bool_predecessorsInSameActionExist_notifyPM = True 'False

    End Sub
        </script>
        <!-- END task predecessor list -->
        <table height="1" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0">
            <tr class="detailHeader" height="1">
                <td width="10" height="1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="200" height="1">Dates</td>
                <td height="1"><IMG height="15" src="../images/whiteslant.gif"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <TABLE class="detailTable" id="Table3" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%">
            <TR class="detailRow">
                <TD class="detailLabel" vAlign="top">Color</TD>
                <TD vAlign="top">:</TD>
                <TD vAlign="top" colSpan="4"><asp:label id="lblColor" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR class="detailRowalt">
                <TD class="detailLabel">Work [Hours(s)]</TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD><asp:label id="lblHours" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
                <TD class="detailLabel">Duration [Day(s)]</TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD><asp:label id="lblDays" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR class="detailRow">
                <TD class="detailLabel" width="20%">Sched Start</TD>
                <TD width="1%">:</TD>
                <TD width="29%"><asp:label id="lblSchedStart" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
                <TD class="detailLabel" width="20%">Sched End</TD>
                <TD width="1%">:</TD>
                <TD width="29%"><asp:label id="lblSchedEnd" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR class="detailRowalt">
                <TD class="detailLabel">Actual Start</TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD><asp:label id="lblActualStart" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
                <TD class="detailLabel">Actual End</TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD><asp:label id="lblActualEnd" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
            </TR>
            <TR class="detailRow">
                <TD class="detailLabel">Projected Start</TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD><asp:label id="lblProjectedStart" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
                <TD class="detailLabel">Projected End</TD>
                <TD>:</TD>
                <TD><asp:label id="lblProjectedEnd" Runat="server"></asp:label></TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
        <!-- == -->
        <asp:panel id="pnl_dynDetails" Runat="server" Visible="False">
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                    <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                    <TD height="1" width="200">* Additional Details</TD>
                    <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <asp:Table id="tbl_dynDetails" Runat="server" Width="100%" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="4"
                CssClass="detailTable"></asp:Table>
        </asp:panel>
        <!-- START PANEL pnl_modifyElements -->
        <asp:panel id="pnl_modifyElements" Runat="server">
            <asp:label id="lbl_debugInfo" Runat="server" visible="false"></asp:label>
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                    <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                    <TD height="1" width="200">* Please fill in all the fields</TD>
                    <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <TABLE id="Table5" class="detailTable" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%">
                <TR class="detailRow">
                    <TD style="HEIGHT: 24px" class="detailLabel" width="20%">Status</TD>
                    <TD style="HEIGHT: 24px" width="1%">:</TD>
                    <TD width="1%">
                        <DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id="divdrpdn_status"><FONT color="red">*</FONT></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD style="HEIGHT: 24px" width="29%" colSpan="4">
                        <asp:dropdownlist id="drpdn_status" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:dropdownlist></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR id="tblRow_actualStartDate" class="detailRowalt" runat="server">
                    <TD class="detailLabel">Actual Start Date</TD>
                    <TD>:</TD>
                    <TD>
                        <DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id="divdatfld_actualStartDate"><FONT color="red">*</FONT></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <Component:DateField id="datfld_actualStartDate" Runat="server" DisallowFutureDates="true" Enabled="true"
                            size="10"></Component:DateField></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR id="tblRow_actualEndDate" class="detailRow" runat="server">
                    <TD class="detailLabel">Actual End Date</TD>
                    <TD>:</TD>
                    <TD>
                        <DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id="divdatfld_actualEndDate"><FONT color="red">*</FONT></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        <Component:DateField id="datfld_actualEndDate" Runat="server" DisallowFutureDates="true" Enabled="true"
                            size="10"></Component:DateField></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR id="tblRow_estimatedEndDate" class="detailRowalt" runat="server">
                    <TD class="detailLabel">Estimated End</TD>
                    <TD>:</TD>
                    <TD>
                        <DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id="divdatfld_estimatedEndDate"><FONT color="red">*</FONT></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD colSpan="4">
                        <Component:DateField id="datfld_estimatedEndDate" Runat="server" DisallowFutureDates="false" Enabled="true"
                            size="10"></Component:DateField></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR id="tblRow_remarks" class="detailRow" runat="server">
                    <TD style="HEIGHT: 24px" class="detailLabel" width="20%">
                        <asp:Label id="lbl_remarks" Runat="server"></asp:Label></TD>
                    <TD style="HEIGHT: 24px" width="1%">:</TD>
                    <TD width="1%">
                        <DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id="divtxtbx_remarks"><FONT color="red">*</FONT></DIV>
                    </TD>
                    <TD style="HEIGHT: 24px" width="29%" colSpan="4">
                        <asp:textbox id="txtbx_remarks" Runat="server" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:textbox></TD>
                </TR> <!--
            <tr class="detailRow">
                <td class="detailLabel" style="CURSOR: hand; COLOR: green; TEXT-DECORATION: underline"
                    onclick="callZoom(33,<%=session("user_id")%>, '<%=session("user_name")%>');" colSpan="6">Analyze your progress</td>
            </tr>
            --></TABLE> <!-- START Deliverable User control -->
            <asp:panel id="pnl_deliverable" Runat="server" visible="true">
                <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="98%" align="center">
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                            <TABLE cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2" width="100%">
                                <TR>
                                    <TD><FONT style="FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma, Verdana; COLOR: darkblue; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">A 
                                            Deliverable is Required </FONT>
                                    </TD>
                                </TR>
                            </TABLE>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR>
                        <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM: darkgray 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: darkgray 1px solid; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-TOP: darkgray 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: darkgray 1px solid"
                            bgColor="aliceblue"></TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
                <UserControl:Deliverable id="usrCntrl_AttachDeliverable" runat="server"></UserControl:Deliverable>
            </asp:panel> 
            <asp:panel id="pnl_condDetailsEdit" Visible="true" Runat="server">
                <TABLE cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" height="1">
                    <TR class="detailHeader" height="1">
                        <TD height="1" width="10">&nbsp;</TD>
                        <TD height="1" width="200"><SPAN>*</SPAN> Conditional Details</TD>
                        <TD height="1"><IMG src="../images/whiteslant.gif" height="15"></TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
                <UserControl:ConditionalDetails id="usrCntrl_ConditionalDetailsPanel" runat="server"></UserControl:ConditionalDetails>
            </asp:panel> <!-- END Conditional Details User control -->
            <asp:button id="btn_save" Runat="server" Text="Save"></asp:button>
            <asp:label id="lbl_btn_save_message" Runat="server" visible="False"></asp:label>
        </asp:panel>
        <asp:panel id="pnl_modifyPerformedMessage" Runat="server">
            <asp:Label id="lbl_modifyPerformedMessage" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </asp:panel>
        <input id="hdn_resourceId" type="hidden" name="hdn_resourceId"> <input id="hdnexplode" type="hidden" name="hdnexplode">
        <input type="hidden" id="RefreshParent" name="RefreshParent"> <input type="hidden" id="hdnSessionTimeout" name="hdnSessionTimeout" runat="server">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On load and rest of server side:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports components
Partial Class toDoListModifyEntity_PT
Inherits BasePage
#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
End Sub
Protected WithEvents NavSpot As System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder
Dim arlist_dynCompnts As ArrayList
Dim gbl_task_Type As Integer = -1
Dim gbl_str_deliverableStatus As String
Public gbl_bool_predecessorsInSameActionExist_notifyPM As Boolean = False
Public gbl_bool_predecessorsInOtherActionExist_notifyAdmin As Boolean = False     
Public gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyPM As Boolean
Public gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyAdmin As Boolean

Protected WithEvents usrCntrl_EntityPredecessor As EntityPredListPanel

Protected WithEvents usrCntrl_ConditionalDetailsPanel As ConditionalDetailsPanel
Private designerPlaceholderDeclaration As System.Object

Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub

#End Region
 Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim DS As SqlDataReader = getEntityDetails(CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), Integer), CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory"), Integer))
    DS.Read()

    If Not IsDBNull(DS.Item("Type")) Then gbl_task_Type = CType(DS.Item("Type"), Integer)

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        fillStatuDropDown(CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), Integer), 13, CType(Session.Item("user_id"), Integer))

        drpdn_status_SelectedIndexChanged(New Object, New System.EventArgs)


        If Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = "13" Then

            datfld_actualStartDate.Text = DS.Item("Actual Start").ToString()
            datfld_actualEndDate.Text = DS.Item("Actual End").ToString()
            datfld_estimatedEndDate.Text = DS.Item("ProjEnd").ToString()
            txtbx_remarks.Text = DS.Item("remark").ToString()

            lblSchedStart.Text = DS.Item("Scheduled Start").ToString()
            lblSchedEnd.Text = DS.Item("Scheduled End").ToString()
            lblActualStart.Text = DS.Item("Actual Start").ToString()
            lblActualEnd.Text = DS.Item("Actual End").ToString()
            lblProjectedStart.Text = DS.Item("ProjStart").ToString()
            lblProjectedEnd.Text = DS.Item("ProjEnd").ToString()
            lblHours.Text = DS.Item("Hours").ToString()
            lblDays.Text = DS.Item("Duration").ToString()

            If IsDBNull(DS.Item("color")) = False Then
                If DS.Item("color") = "G" Then
                    lblColor.Text = "<img src=""../images/G.gif""> Green"
                ElseIf DS.Item("color") = "Y" Then
                    lblColor.Text = "<img src=""../images/Y.gif""> Yellow"
                ElseIf DS.Item("color") = "O" Then
                    lblColor.Text = "<img src=""../images/O.gif""> Orange"
                ElseIf DS.Item("color") = "R" Then
                    lblColor.Text = "<img src=""../images/R.gif""> Red"
                Else
                    lblColor.Text = "None"
                End If
            Else
                lblColor.Text = "None"
            End If

            If lblActualStart.Text <> "" Then
                lblProjectedStart.Visible = False
            Else
                lblProjectedStart.Visible = True
            End If

        End If


    End If

    DS.Close()


    If Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = "13" Then

        pnl_dynDetails.Visible = False
        If gbl_task_Type <> -1 Then
            pnl_dynDetails.Visible = True
            arlist_dynCompnts = New ArrayList
            CustomFieldsLibrary.editDynamicFields(tbl_dynDetails, CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), Integer), 13, gbl_task_Type, arlist_dynCompnts, (New SqlConnection((New ConnInfo).GetConnString)), True)
            'CustomControls.CustomFieldsLibrary.showDynamicDetails(tbl_dynDetails, CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), Integer), 13, task_Type, Nothing, (New SqlConnection((New ConnInfo).GetConnString)), True)
        End If

    End If


    gbl_str_deliverableStatus = ExecutionFunctions.checkEntityDeliverableStatus(CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), String))
    lbl_debugInfo.Text += System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " gbl_str_deliverableStatus: '" + gbl_str_deliverableStatus + "'<br />"



    gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyPM = ExecutionFunctions.checkEarlyProgressAlreadyMarked_PM(CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), String))


    gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyAdmin = False 

    If gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyPM Then
        pnl_msg_predecessorsInSameAction.Visible = False
        pnl_msg_predecessorsActionLinked.Visible = False

        pnl_msg_earlyProgressAlreadyMarked_notifiedPM.Visible = True
    Else
        pnl_msg_earlyProgressAlreadyMarked_notifiedPM.Visible = False
    End If

    If gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyAdmin Then
        pnl_msg_predecessorsInSameAction.Visible = False
        pnl_msg_predecessorsActionLinked.Visible = False
        pnl_msg_earlyProgressAlreadyMarked_notifiedPM.Visible = False

        pnl_msg_earlyProgressAlreadyMarked_notifiedAdmin.Visible = True
    Else
        pnl_msg_earlyProgressAlreadyMarked_notifiedAdmin.Visible = False
    End If

    If gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyAdmin Or gbl_bool_earlyStatusAlreadyMarked_notifyPM Then
        pnl_modifyElements.Visible = False
    Else
        pnl_modifyElements.Visible = True
    End If

    btn_save.Attributes("onClick") = "return validate(this.form);"

    lbl_debugInfo.Text += "Page_Load END<br />"

End Sub
```

drpdn_status_SelectedIndexChanged:

```
Private Sub drpdn_status_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles drpdn_status.SelectedIndexChanged

    lbl_remarks.Text = drpdn_status.SelectedItem.Text + " Remarks"

    Select Case drpdn_status.SelectedValue 
        Case 7 
            tblRow_actualStartDate.Visible = True
            tblRow_actualEndDate.Visible = False
            tblRow_estimatedEndDate.Visible = False
            tblRow_remarks.Visible = False

            pnl_deliverable.Visible = False

        Case 8 
            tblRow_actualStartDate.Visible = True
            tblRow_actualEndDate.Visible = False
            tblRow_estimatedEndDate.Visible = True
            tblRow_remarks.Visible = True

            pnl_deliverable.Visible = False

        Case 15 
            tblRow_actualStartDate.Visible = True
            tblRow_actualEndDate.Visible = False
            tblRow_estimatedEndDate.Visible = True
            tblRow_remarks.Visible = False

            pnl_deliverable.Visible = False

        Case 9 
            tblRow_actualStartDate.Visible = True
            tblRow_actualEndDate.Visible = True
            tblRow_estimatedEndDate.Visible = False
            tblRow_remarks.Visible = True

            Dim str_deliverableStatus As String = ExecutionFunctions.checkEntityDeliverableStatus(CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), String))

            If str_deliverableStatus = "1" Then pnl_deliverable.Visible = True

            lbl_debugInfo.Text += "Local str_deliverableStatus: '" + str_deliverableStatus + "'<br />"
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("ERROR: unrecognized status *Value* (" + drpdn_status.SelectedItem.Value.ToString + ")")

    End Select


End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

update: if I replace the onload with only a clientscript to just pop up an alert to let us know the page load is being ran, it works on the development side but still nothing happens on the server side. Even though we call a function (fillStatuDropDown) to fill the dropdown on load - the dropdown on the deployment side is loaded with two values even though we have removed all calls to the function that fills the dropdown, on the development side it doesn't fill any values into the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to corruption from FTP deployment. Was able to reupload the whole application and everything then worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your page AutoEventWireup is at false, where is the event attached?

Also, there's some kind of logic issue in your Page_Load.

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    fillStatuDropDown(CType(Page.Request.QueryString("taskgrpid"), Integer), 13,    CType(Session.Item("user_id"), Integer))

    drpdn_status_SelectedIndexChanged(New Object, New System.EventArgs)
```

Let's take the case where you load the page the first time, the SelectedIndexChanged event is then attached correctly but if you change the index, another postback occurs the selectedIndexChanged event will not be attached causing the event not to be fired.

Comment: shouldn't that be taken care of by the codebehind section of the same line? wasn't too sure about this part. It seems every page in this section of the application has the autoeventwireup to false, but this is the only page giving issues with the onload and the selectedindexchanged functions not running.

Comment: If the page AutoEventWireUp is at false, then the Page_Load event should not fire except if it's explicitly defined in the code behind or in a inherited class(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324151/en-us). It's this is not the problem, provide the full code of your page. EDIT: This can also be defined in the web.config

Comment: The whole code of the page is listed above, except for a few small javascript functions that auto update some of the text box fields, which are working correctly. The onload and selectedindexchanged functions above should also provide enough as the rest of the code from this server side page is not relevant to the onload issue.

Comment: Of course the rest of the server side page is relevant, it's the only thing that's relevant. How is the code from the seletedindexchange function relevant if it's not even firing? Please update the page with your entire server side code. Also, please check this attribute in your deployed web.config(the one that is not working) <pages autoEventWireup="true|false" />

Comment: added the rest of server side.

Comment: the load event is probably attached in your BasePage but can you check that it is just to be sure?

Comment: will post basepage below, took end calls off so it fits in comment

Comment: Imports System.Web.Configuration
Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("SessionCheck") = "1" Then
            If Session("User_Id") Is Nothing Then
                Response.Write("<script language=JavaScript>")
                Response.Write("top.location.replace('" & WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("RedirectPage") & "')")
                Response.Write("</script>")
                Response.End()
            End If

Comment: the selectedindexchanged event is not happening even once on the page load- so its not attaching correctly even on the first post back

Comment: I don't see anywhere the load event attached, try it and tell me if it works

Comment: I have multiple pages set up with `autoeventwireup` set to false and they work as expected so I don't think that is your issue. The main difference I see is that my `Page_Load` functions handle the `Me.Load` event and not the `MyBase.Load` event.

Comment: does't look like it has to do with the me.Load vs the MyBase.Load - it is set to MyBase through out the application, switching to me.load works on the development side just like mybase does, but still does not work when deployed.

Comment: another issue i have noticed is if in the development side if i comment out the fillStatusDropdown function call, I get an error when it attempts to call the drpdn_status_selectedindexchanged - but when I upload this code with the comment to the deployed site, The ddl is filled with items still and no error happens on load.

Comment: do you have a test server you can publish too that is completely under your control? just to rule out the server setup being an issue...

Comment: Only option right now is to publish to our amazon EC2 set up which i have been doing.

Comment: added update to the first post, nothing on page load is running on the development side, yet somehow the dropdown is filled with values.